# How to authenticate a user using a teams bot using my own custom authentication service?

Tags: node.js, authentication, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have created a bot on azure and registered it in bot registration channel. Now I want to authenticate the user using the bot using my own custom authentication service hosted like https://domainname/auth.
I have no idea how to do it. I have read oauth on bot framework docs but did not find any tutorial to integrate my own authentication service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could navigate to your Bot Channel Registration -> Settings -> Oauth Connection Settings -> Add Setting

[image]

In the New Connection Setting page, could fill in the details of your Auth provider after selecting the service provider as Generic Oauth2.

[image]

For more information you could refer to the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample#create-the-identity-provider) to learn about configuring and using the same.

Comment: thanks @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT. In the 2nd image Authorization URL will be my custom url then what is Token URL and Refresh URL?

Comment: If I am not wrong this will be present at your IdP that is implemented at your end. For Eg, talking Azure IDP. If you see the flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/media/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow/convergence-scenarios-native.svg 

You can see auth url (2.0/auth) and token (2.0/token) for token & token Refresh endpoint

Similarly you will have configuration for your custom IdP. if everything is same at your end, you can provide the same endpoint to Token URL and Refresh URL.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma - https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/protocol-oauth2#authorization-endpoint  

This article details of the Authorizing endpoint and the token endpoint. Sharing it for your reference.

Comment: thanks @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT that was very helpful

Comment: @AbhishekSharma - Glad I could've helped. Pls consider marking this as the answer if it met your requirement :)